# How do I package a Vagrant box with custom Vagrant file (public network, RAM settings, etc.)

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I packaged a VirtualBox with all the settings I wanted. I set network to 'bridged adapter' (Vagrant calls it 'public_network'). I even looked at `box.ovf` in the `.box` file and it said

```
$ tar xOf nycmesh-qmp-openwrt.box box.ovf | less
  <NetworkSection>
    <Info>Logical networks used in the package</Info>
    <Network ovf:name="Bridged">
      <Description>Logical network used by this appliance.</Description>
```

But when I tried to add the box with `vagrant box add box-name box.box`, and `init` the box, then it generated the machine *without* a bridged adapter. It used NAT.

I even updated the `.box` file (which is a gzipped tar file) and overwrote the `Vagrantfile` with my custom `Vagrantfile` which had

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

I re-added the box (with `--force`), ran `vagrant init box-name` again, and it still generated a `Vagrantfile` with `config.vm.network` commented out!

So, *how*?

Vagrant 2.0.1

---

This is my manually created VM network in VirtualBox:

[image: network original node]

I created `package-the-vagrantfile/Vagrantfile` containing

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "64"
  end
end
```

According to the documentation

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html

I package this VM with

```
$ vagrant package --base node --vagrantfile package-the-vagrantfile/Vagrantfile
```

It creates `package.box`. I instantiate the box with

```
$ vagrant init package.box --minimal ; vagrant up
```

It starts up a new box...

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'package.box'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: node_default_1522176655197_96615
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
```

But it has the wrong network

[image: network of new node]

It does have the correct memory

[image: memory]

The network directive is in the box too.

```
$ tar -xOf package.box ./include/_Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
...
$ tar -xOf package.box ./Vagrantfile
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
...
# Load include vagrant file if it exists after the auto-generated
# so it can override any of the settings
include_vagrantfile = File.expand_path("../include/_Vagrantfile", __FILE__)
load include_vagrantfile if File.exist?(include_vagrantfile)
```